# Python logging to console window randomly on different machines

Tags: python, logging

I have a Python script that utilizes the logging module to log messages to a file. And in most cases it works just fine, but on some of my co-worker's machines it is logging every message from every imported module to the console window. There doesn't seem to be any pattern as to why this is working on some machines and not on others.

Here is how I set up the logger

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parser.parse_args()

    logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.NullHandler()]) #do this so that imported modules don't screw with logging
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler = logging.FileHandler(args.log)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    logger.info(str(args))
    main(args)
```

So what's happening is first I set up my logger as a global variable, then I use basicConfig to set the root handler as the NullHandler(), this is so that any imported modules won't log anything to my log file or my console window, and finally I set my logger to log to a log file provided in the program arguments.

This works exactly how I want to on my machine, the log file is only written to when I use my `logger` object. No log messages are passed to my console window and no log messages from imported modules go to my log file.

However, on a few random machines, every single call to `logging` or `logger` goes to the console window. The logs in the log file are ok, they only show the logs I expect them to (the ones called with `logger`).

For instance, when I do `logger.info(str(args))`,

`INFO: Namespace(arg1='Foo', arg2='Bar', arg3='foobar')`

is outputted to the console window.

I can't think of any reason that this would behave differently on different machines. It is the exact same script, the same version of python, and the same version of logging. Any ideas?

Comment: I just tested on my machine, and could "replicate" the messages going into console under py2 and silence under py3.
My best bet is that the python version is **not** the same. In py2 there's no `handlers` arg in basicConfig() and it will be ignored. 
I know you said that py version is indeed the same but can you double check?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, forgot that I created this issue. You are correct, the python version was in fact py2. Updating it to py3 solved it. Thanks for the help!